# sample project template intellij Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

when i create a project from template and try to run in Application server tomcat 
i got

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
```

this is from project template .. and i followed the instruction from 
[Getting Started with Spring MVC, Hibernate and JSON](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON)

i configured the Application Server as Tomcat 8

any suggestion ??, i found a lots of similar problem in stackoverflow but not the project template ..

[image: dis-servlets]

[image: web.xml]

Stacktrace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: post the `web.xml` and `servlet-context.xml`

Comment: @M.Sharma are you willing to plow through configurations without knowing the exact exception?

Comment: Please show your complete stacktrace and configurations

Comment: @Bart http 500 i believe is internal server error so there must be some configuration mistake

Comment: @M.Sharma It could be. An internal server error could be anything :)

Comment: i followed configuration at the link above ..

Comment: your image shows something is throwing error as there is red underline

Comment: under line is the test , i clean maven from test dependency .. now it looks clear

Comment: rebuild and redeploy now

Comment: still with this 500 error

Comment: @M.Sharma the latest image after build ...

Comment: shouln't there be <mvc:annotation-driven /> in the context?

Comment: please dont add image it is very hard to read and please post that stacktrace generated

Comment: Have you tried using Tomcat 7?

Comment: @geoand no , am using Apache Tomcat/8.0.9 , do you recommended it ??

Comment: add this line on servlet.xml `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and redeploy it

Comment: intellij found namespace not in bound

Comment: @YassineAbdul-Rahman I would check it to make that the Tomcat version is not the problem

Comment: add this namespace `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` in xsi-schemaLocation

Comment: @M.Sharma can you show me some links that may help please .. i found dozen b

Comment: this appeared simple to me `http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-hello-world/`

Comment: There is a fixed version of this tutorial in this git repository available for those, who has problem to find together all the fixes: https://bitbucket.org/cg-lab/intellij-getting-started-with-spring-mvc-hibernate-and-json

Answer (score 0):

People have reported problems with ASM on Java 8 so if you are using Java 8 I'd suggest dropping it down to 7 for the moment to avoid the issues. That should solve your problem.

Or else you could try changing your spring version to at least 4.0.3 if its lower than that as I believe that has the latest ASM version and fully supports java 8.